# Change of coordinates when first partial derivative is nonzero

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Suppose $F:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is smooth where $U\subset \mathbb{R}^{m}$ is open with coordinates $(x_{1},...,x_{m})$, and suppose that $a\in U$ is a critical point such that $\frac{\partial F^{1}}{\partial x_{1}}(a)\neq 0$.  I want to show that $\phi(x_{1},...,x_{m})=(u,v_{2},...,v_{m})$ where $u=F^{1}(x_{1},..,x_{m})$ and $v_{i}=x_{i}$ for $i=2,..,m$, defines a change of coordinates on some neighborhood of $a$, i.e., is a homeomorphism on some neighborhood of $a$ into $\mathbb{R}^{m}$.  This should follow because the corresponding Jacobian is nonsingular at $a$, but what theorem would give me this?  How would I write the inverse of $\phi$ in coordinates?

If I knew that $F^{1}$ was injective in some neigherborhood, then I could conclude the same about $\phi$, and hence $\phi$ would be a diffeomorphism.  The Jacobian of $F$ is nonsingular at $a$ and so it defines a diffeomorphism in some neighborhood of $a$, but this doesn't imply that $F^{1}$ is injective there.

Edit: What is the coordinate representation of $F$ in these new coordinates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is much simpler. The equation $u=F^1(x_1,x_2,..,x_n)$ defines an implicit function $ X_1(u,x_2,...,x_n)$. Just by the Implicit Function Theorem. So the inverse of $\phi$ is just $\psi (u,x_2,..x_n)=(X_1(u,x_2,..x_n),x_2,...x_n)$

Comment: The coordinate representation of $F$ is supposed to be $F(u,v)=(u,F^{2}(u,v),...,F^{n}(u,v))$.  But $F\circ \psi (u,v)=F(X_{1}(u,v),v)=(u,F^{2}(X_{1}(u,v),v),...,F^{n}(X_{1}(u,v),v))$ and $X_{1}(u,v)\neq u$.

Comment: I don't know how the coordinate representation makes sense because the IFT was only applied to $F^{1}$, the other components of $F$ don't come into it.